# I'm trying to change the background color of textarea in scenebuilder, but the outline color is changing

Tags: javafx, textarea, background-color, scenebuilder, javafx-css

In similar questions, it was written that if you set the background-color style, the background color will change, but in my case the outline changes

Scene Builder configuration:

[image: image showing Scene Builder style field]

Result:

[image: image showing result]

And for some reason the outline is not for the entire rectangle.

Comment: Take a look at the [substructure of the default `TextArea` skin](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/18/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#text-area). Most likely you want to set the background of the `content`, and for that you'll likely need an external stylesheet to do e.g., `.text-area .content { -fx-background-color: red; }`.

Comment: @Slaw it worked. Is there a way to get the same result, but not to connect a separate file using only the style tab in scenebuilder?

Comment: No, I don't think there's a way to do this only via _Scene Builder_. I'm not familiar with all its capabilities, but given how CSS and `style` works, I don't see how you could do this via CSS without an external stylesheet. Though you can add a stylesheet via FXML (including via _Scene Builder_). Programmatically, you could do something like `theTextArea.lookup(".content").setStyle("-fx-background-color: red")`, but only after the skin has been initialized (which doesn't typically happen until the control is being displayed in a scene).

Answer (score 0):

Try to look at your xml file, it should be written something like this:
style="-fx-background-color: #FFF5EE; -fx-border-color: #FFF5EE